# How to kill process group zombies

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, error-handling

Hypothetically, let's say main() function creates second process calling fork() and let's say this new process starts creating its own children by function makeChildren(), one million in loop, crazy user. Fork() fails, makeChildren() returns error. How to get rid off these new processes that have been already created? Can I use killpg(getpgrp(), SIGKILL) ??? If I understand it right each process in this scenario has same group ID, no? When I use killpg(getpgrp(), SIGKILL) program will terminate immediately, am I right? Do I have to use setpgid()? I want to kill this zombies and in main release shared memory, semaphores and so on ...  Thank you for any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parent process terminates, its children will be reassigned to the `init` process. It will `wait` for them so they shouldn't become zombies.

Comment: Yes, but when I run this program, my system, debian/Linux 3.14 starts lagging and freeze and I have to restart it.

Comment: Your processes aren't zombies. If they're still running when the parent died, they're called orphan processes and the init process reaps them when they eventually terminate. So your issue is not about killing zombie processes. Since the children processes still run, you have plenty of choice: test if they parent's id is 1, use a lock file or some kind of IPC to see if the parent is running, and if not, make them terminate.